# Fedora fails to start and lost shell access

Tags: fedora, boot, su, lightdm

**Linux Dist: Fedora 31 Mate compiz.

Dual boot with win10.** (UEFI secure boot enabled).

**1)**
While shutting down the system, an unusual errors showed up in the screen.
[image]

So the problem started with Lightdm.
**2)** On the next boot,Emergency mode appeared , i followed the journalctl and figure out that i have to fix the partitions using  fsck wich i did  ,And on the next boot  it stucked on Login Service step: (unable to get the tty )
[image]

**3)** I tried to start emergency mode to check the journalctl (systemd.unit=emergency.target), and i got this:
[image]

**Edit : (Using live USB )**

```
$fdisk - l 
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7B2B9D8A-6958-447F-8199-612492FE6C18

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    1023999   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    1024000    1228799    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1228800    1261567     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1261568  356085759 354824192 169.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  356085760  358182911   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  358182912 1213837311 855654400   408G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.51 GiB, 8053063680 bytes, 15728640 sectors
Disk model: Flash Disk      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x03f6914f

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 15728639 15726592  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost-root: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost-home: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost-swap: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.91 GiB, 2032271360 bytes, 3969280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 7 GiB, 7518289920 bytes, 14684160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 32 GiB, 34359738368 bytes, 67108864 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/live-rw: 7 GiB, 7518289920 bytes, 14684160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/live-base: 7 GiB, 7518289920 bytes, 14684160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**Lsblk**

```
$lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0   1.9G  1 loop 
loop1                       7:1    0     7G  1 loop 
├─live-rw                 253:3    0     7G  0 dm   /
└─live-base               253:4    0     7G  1 dm   
loop2                       7:2    0    32G  0 loop 
└─live-rw                 253:3    0     7G  0 dm   /
sda                         8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   499M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda3                      8:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda4                      8:4    0 169.2G  0 part 
├─sda5                      8:5    0     1G  0 part 
└─sda6                      8:6    0   408G  0 part 
  ├─fedora_localhost-root 253:0    0   200G  0 lvm  
  ├─fedora_localhost-home 253:1    0   200G  0 lvm  
  └─fedora_localhost-swap 253:2    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                         8:16   1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1                      8:17   1   7.5G  0 part /run/initramfs/live
sr0                        11:0    1   2.6M  0 rom  /run/media/liveuser/HiSuite
```

I checked the /bin directory and noticed that the `bash` was not there so i copied the one provided in the live-usb .And i was able to login again, but i have found out that many commands are not found and in every terminal opening i got this errors:

```
bash: /usr/bin/register-python-argcomplete: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
bash: awk: command not found
bash: /usr/bin/powerline-daemon: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/bin/powerline-config: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/bin/powerline-config: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
[cuore@localhost ~]$ dnf
bash: /usr/bin/dnf: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
[cuore@localhost ~]$ cat
bash: cat: command not found
[cuore@localhost ~]$
```

```
$ sudo rpm --verify --all
missing     /usr/bin/aulastlog
missing     /usr/bin/ausyscall
missing     /usr/bin/auvirt
missing   a /usr/lib/.build-id/10/0eaa49fad105bff332a1e61f1ac5b761872c5f
missing     /usr/bin/audit2allow
missing     /usr/bin/audit2why
missing     /usr/bin/chcat
missing     /usr/bin/checkisomd5
missing     /usr/include/arpa
missing     /usr/include/arpa/ftp.h
missing     /usr/include/arpa/inet.h
missing     /usr/include/arpa/nameser.h
missing     /usr/include/arpa/nameser_compat.h
missing     /usr/include/arpa/telnet.h
missing     /usr/include/arpa/tftp.h
missing     /usr/include/bits
missing     /usr/include/bits/a.out.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/argp-ldbl.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/byteswap.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/cmathcalls.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/confname.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/cpu-set.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/dirent.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/dirent_ext.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/dlfcn.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/elfclass.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/endian.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/environments.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/epoll.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/err-ldbl.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/errno.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/error-ldbl.h
missing     /usr/include/bits/error.h
.......... **And MORE**
```

It looks like i am having the same problem as in [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/troubles-with-dnf-python-dependencies-or-dnf-is-brocken/3151/10).
The only thing that i can think of that probably caused the deletion of multiple critical files is at the step when i manually runned fsck over `fedora_localhost-root` `fedora_localhost-home`.
Can it be it?

Comment: Do you have the log from the fsck of the root filesystem? Also please add more details on your exact storage setup (devices, RAID, LVM, partitions, filesystems, etc.).

Comment: @TooTea can't get any sort of shell . sorry

Comment: But perhaps you remember what HW do you have in the machine and how you set the storage up. If not, just boot from a live USB stick (preferably the same Fedora release) and continue troubleshooting from there. If that's not possible, you can use the rescue initramfs to troubleshoot your system, but that's way less comfortable than a full-blown live OS.

Comment: I just found a USB stick ( Lucky me .. it's hard to get one when you are quarantined Lol). i will ll give you updates..

Comment: @TooTea Check the updates : )

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, it looks like the login shell for the root user is not set properly in the `/etc/passwd` file.

can you `ctrl+alt+f2,f3,f4` to get to a tty?

Comment: i get the tty but when i enter login/passwd, it just go back to demand those info again..

Comment: Check The updates : )